# SchemaFactory Sonar Disable access to external entities in XML parsing - how to fix?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar proposes compliant solution for SchemaFactory as follows:

```java
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
// to be compliant, completely disable DOCTYPE declaration:
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
// or prohibit the use of all protocols by external entities:
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

It clearly says disable DOCTYPE declaration **or** prohibit the use of all protocols by external entities so I chose the 1st option.
[image: Sonar finding]

Any clues how to fix this without setting external properties? Is it a bug in Sonar or am I missing something? I used `newInstance()` with specific factory class argument but I don't think it should influence the security rule.

Comment: Try the second option.  Documented properties are more reliable than an undocumented property.  You may also want to add `factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true)`.

Comment: I checked all options and sonar only accepts solution with disabled `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_*` flags. In my case I can suppress the warning as I'm using schema from project resources. Nevertheless the description is misleading.

Comment: I have many times written code with a comment like `// Make sonar happy`.  Sonar has a lot of flaws.  Secure XML processing is a good thing, but I can’t think of a justification for only accepting the doctype approach.